# Can HP EliteBook 840 G7 Notebook drive a 5k2k display?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display, thunderbolt

My employer provides my with a [HP EliteBook 840 G7 Notebook](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c06603706.pdf). I'd like to buy a external monitor for it, and I came across the [Dell UltraSharp 40 Curved WUHD Monitor - U4021QW](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-40-curved-wuhd-monitor-u4021qw/apd/210-aykx/monitors-monitor-accessories). I'm somewhat confused by the HP description of the laptops capability of running a 5k2k monitor like the Dell:

1. On Page two of the [QuickSpecs](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c06603706.pdf), it says under point 4 and 5 "SuperSpeed USB Type-C® 5Gbps signaling rate ® with ThunderboltTM". I thought Thunderbolt is always 40Gbit/s? Why would Dell mention "5Gbps"?
2. On Page seven of the [QuickSpecs](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c06603706.pdf), it says the laptop can drive a single 5k Display at 60Hz, when a HP USB-C Universal Dock G2 is used. Can I use a third-party thunderbolt dock (e.g. [OWC Thunderbolt 3 Docking Station](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock-14-port)) to run the [Dell UltraSharp 40 Curved WUHD Monitor - U4021QW](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-40-curved-wuhd-monitor-u4021qw/apd/210-aykx/monitors-monitor-accessories), or is laptop only capable of running a 5k display with the Dell specific dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not for a long time w/o cooking eggs :) , based on your model you've specified HP EliteBook 840 G7 Notebook and looking at the [detailed technical specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06680927#AbT3) You'll see the graphics are integrated Intel UHD Graphics w/ every CPU combination.So w/out providing your specific CPU combination we can't determine what [Intel UHD Graphics](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@PanelLabel211968) chipset was shipped w/ your laptop.

Maybe you got the cheapest Intel processor for the model in question

-Intel Core i5-10210U Processor, which is a [10th Gen Intel Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/195436/intel-core-i510210u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) that shows:

- 4K Support - Yes, at 60Hz  Max Resolution (HDMI)‡ 4096 x 2304@24Hz
- Max Resolution (DP)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz
- Max Resolution (eDP -Integrated Flat Panel)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz

Or maybe you got the most expensive Intel processor for the model in question

-Intel Core i7-10810U Processor, which is a [10th Gen Intel Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201888/intel-core-i710810u-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html) that shows:

- 4K Support - Yes, at 60Hz  Max Resolution (HDMI)‡ 4096 x 2304@24Hz
- Max Resolution (DP)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz
- Max Resolution (eDP -Integrated Flat Panel)‡ 4096 x 2304@60Hz

But lo and behold they're the same spec...

If you got the latest 11th Gen Intel [Intel® Core™ i7-11850HE](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/217379/intel-core-i711850he-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz.html)
now your graphics specs w/an integrated driver are:

- Max Resolution (HDMI)‡ 4096x2304@60Hz
- Max Resolution (DP)‡ 7680x4320@60Hz
- Max Resolution (eDP - Integrated Flat Panel)‡ 4096x2304@60Hz

The monitor in question: [Dell UltraSharp 40 Curved WUHD Monitor - U4021QW Tech Specs](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-40-curved-wuhd-monitor-u4021qw/apd/210-aykx/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section):

- Native Resolution - 5120 x 2160 at 60Hz

Take look at page 18 of the [Users Guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-u4021qw-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf) will answer all your questions about the speeds/data transfers. But you may have to update to the latest Intel driver Page 76 has points of why it may or may not display. I would definitely recommend going w/ a dock to avoid overworking your laptop but a dock w/ some type of integrated graphics and that you have vetted the Graphics Chip set is capable of driving that sweet monitor.

Answer (score 1):

By the specs, your USB ports are of type "USB 3.2 Gen 1×1".

[Wikipedia USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)
has this table:

[image]

The fact that Thunderbolt is supported just means that your motherboard
will accept Thunderbolt devices, but at its speed only.

Logically speaking, any Thunderbolt dock should do, but hardware
compatibility is not something that can be guaranteed.
The only way to be sure is to try it.

Comment: Small clarification the laptop will support the appropriate revision of Thunderbolt at USB USB 3.2 Gen 1×1 speeds.  I believe that is Thunderbolt 3+ due to the reverse compatibility with USB Type-C